# Redshift : NVARCHAR / NCHAR in DDL

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to get all of ddl from our production database. We need to contain the Japanese, doudle-byte characters, so we set some columns 'NVARCHAR' or 'NCHAR'.
Since if we set VARCHAR or CHAR for the table columns, the data contains double-byte characters, got to be load error when copying from S3 to Redshift.

However, when I try to get ddl by any way like 'v_generate_tbl_ddl', command 'show table', and create ddl by tools of Aginity or Workbench/J, they all converted to 'VARCHAR' or 'CHAR'.

Is there any way to get right ddl with NVARCHAR/NCHAR or someone know the reason about this conversion?

Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

NVARCHAR is an alias for VARCHAR, so the generated DDL will show VARCHAR for the column type. From the documentation:

> You can create columns with the NCHAR and NVARCHAR types (also known as NATIONAL CHARACTER and NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING types). These types are converted to CHAR and VARCHAR types, respectively, and are stored in the specified number of bytes.
>
> An NCHAR column without a length specification is converted to a CHAR(1) column.
>
> An NVARCHAR column without a length specification is converted to a VARCHAR(256) column.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html#r_Character_types-nchar-and-nvarchar-types

The documentation also states that VARCHAR columns can contain multi-byte characters. CHAR columns can only contain single byte characters. Could you resolve your load errors by changing your CHAR columns to VARCHAR?

> Use a VARCHAR or CHARACTER VARYING column to store variable-length strings with a fixed limit. These strings are not padded with blanks, so a VARCHAR(120) column consists of a maximum of 120 single-byte characters, 60 two-byte characters, 40 three-byte characters, or 30 four-byte characters.